# Converting string to unordered list

Tags: html-lists, stenciljs

For a random experiment, I was trying to build a shopping list, using Stencil. My input would be a string, ie. "cauliflower, cucumber" with ingredients on the shopping list. I would like this string to be converted in an unordered list.

Converting the string to an array is no problem. Going from the array to the list, I tried using a for loop, looping through all options in the array and adding them to the list.

```js
export class ShoppingList {

  @Prop() veggies: string;

private makeList(typeString: string): HTMLUListElement {
    var listArray: string[] = typeString.split(',');
    for(var i=0; i<listArray.length; i++) {
      // Create the list element:
      var list = document.createElement('ul');

      // Create the list item:
      var item = document.createElement('li');

      // Set its contents:
      item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(listArray[i]));

      // Add it to the list:
      list.appendChild(item);
    }

    return list;
  }

  private getVeggies(): HTMLUListElement {
    return this.makeList(this.veggies);
  }

render() {
    return (
      <div>
        veggies: 
        <ul>{this.getVeggies()}</ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The index.html file runs this code through the following line: 
`<shopping-list veggies="Cauliflower, cucumber" ></shopping-list>`

I expected an output of `veggies: * cauliflower \n *cucumber`. Instead, I just get `veggies:` with an empty list. When inspecting the elements, I get the following HTML output:

`<div>veggies:<ul><undefined></undefined> </ul><br></div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing DOM nodes and [VDOM nodes](https://stenciljs.com/docs/templating-jsx). With the VDOM you can remove the code manually creating DOM nodes:

```js
export class ShoppingList {

  @Prop() veggies: string;

  private makeList(typeString: string): HTMLUListElement {
    var listArray: string[] = typeString.split(',');

    return (
      <ul>
            {listArray.map((item) => <li>{item}</li>)}
      </ul>
    );

  private getVeggies(): HTMLUListElement {
    return this.makeList(this.veggies);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        veggies: 
        {this.getVeggies()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

First of all, I changed `makeList` so it returns VDOM and [loop over the items](https://stenciljs.com/docs/templating-jsx#loops) with `map` instead of a `for` loop. Also I removed the `<ul>` from the `render()` method since `makeList` already returns it.